# I want the first li be opened by default and when I click on an "a" tag that is opened the ul following don't close

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
   Here my html :
    <ul id="navLeft">
      <li>
        <a class="nav_a">aaaa</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li><a>1111</a></li>
          <li><a>1111</a></li>
          <li><a>1111</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav_a">bbbb</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li><a>2222</a></li>
          <li><a>2222</a></li>
          <li><a>2222</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav_a">cccc</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li><a>3333</a></li>
          <li><a>3333</a></li>
          <li><a>3333</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    
    CSS:
     .children{
      display: none;
    }


jquery:
     $(".nav_a").click(function () {
        $('ul.children').not($(this).next('ul.children')).removeClass("expanded").slideUp();
        $(this).next('ul.children').toggleClass("expanded").slideToggle(250);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(".nav_a").click(function () {
         if($(this).next('ul.children').hasClass("expanded"))
      return;    
  
  $('ul.children').not($(this).next('ul.children')).removeClass("expanded").slideUp();
        $(this).next('ul.children').toggleClass("expanded").slideToggle(250);

});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
#navLeft li:first-child .children{
 display:block;
}
```

I hope this css is what you are looking for. If this is not working Please give a detailed description.

Comment: Yess that's work. Thank youu, I need also that when I click on a "li a" that are opened , the following li list on it don't close.

Comment: Doy you want to close the list even if you click on the li a inside the opened list. Am I correct?

Comment: No, I just want to keep the list opened even when I click on the li a above. For example: let's say the list cccc is opened and appear the list 3333 3 times,  I want that this list 3333 still appear when I click cccc again and don't close. Thank youuu.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Check the below script instead of your script and tell me this is what you are looking for.

```
$('#navLeft li>a').click(function(){
    $('ul.children').not($(this).next('ul.children')).removeClass("expanded").slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul.children').toggleClass("expanded").slideToggle(250);
});
```

If this is what you are trying to acheive then don't forget to mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: No, this doesn't work as I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#navLeft li>a').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul.children').toggleClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
    });
```

Try the above script instead of the script You are using